# Customer Community VF page issue with Javacript Pop Up

Tags: visualforce, community, customer-portal, customer-community

I have VF page which opens popup via link it's working fine in the org but not in Sales-force Community:error is down for maintenance.

I have below page link which opens up as pop up and I need it as a pop up can't use window.parent to open in same page or something:

```
<apex:outputLink onclick="openPopup();">
```

My javascirpt funciton:

```
  function openPopup(){
    window.open('/Mypage','_blank','toolbar=yes, scrollbars=yes, resizable=yes, top=500, left=500, width=400, height=400')    
    }
```

Gave access of vf page in customer comm profile and also in public sites

Comment: Do you miss the subdomain in url? Hardcoding URLs is bad, try using $Page.PageName for URL navigation

Comment: Still it does not work ...same with /Mypage  ..can you share snippet how will I use subdomain ??

Comment: Open any other standard or custom page which works, see the complete URL and try finding what's missing in URL.

Comment: Everything is working fine in my org as stated in my question

Comment: What is your community URL. The final URL should not include apex

Comment: Hi Eric, tried that as well but if show same error removed apex and used /mypage.